# advanced custom fields archive

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I've created a custom post using advanced custom fields on my wordpress theme. Its a profile page that displays a users basic info plus a gallery section titled weekly activity and an archive section. I would like to archive the gallery displayed under "weekly activity" so that the archives are listed on the page under "archives". I'm not quite sure how to tackle that particular are. Here is my code for the front-end template:

```
 <?php get_header(); ?>
 <?php the_post(); ?>
 <div class = "hcontainer">
   <div class = "leftcol">
    <?php 
    $image = get_field('profile_picture');
    if( !empty($image) ): ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <p class ="lfeilds">Name:<?php the_field('name'); ?></p>
    <p class ="lfeilds">Age:<?php the_field('age'); ?></p>
    <p class ="lfeilds">Gender:<?php the_field('gender'); ?></p>
    <p class ="larchive">Gallery Archive</p>
   ***<?php the_field('archive'); ?>***
   </div>
   <div class ="rightcol">
     <p class ="rtitle">Weekly Activities</p>
     <div class ="rgallery">
      <?php 
      $image_ids = get_field('gallery', false, false);
      $shortcode = '[gallery ids="' . implode(',', $image_ids) . '"]';
      echo do_shortcode( $shortcode );
      ?>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What type of field is your 'archive'?

Comment: basically it will be an archive of the gallery feild

Comment: Right okay, so whats the difference between the gallery and the gallery archive?

Comment: The gallery will display a collection of images while the gallery archive will just be a listed view of the gallery's based on the date they were created. Just like normal WordPress archives